# PostSharp 5.1.9 - Build fail on linux hosted build server .net core 2 pos

Tags: azure-pipelines, postsharp, .net-core-2.0

I am trying to build with Linux hosted build server, but I am getting an error.

See the log:

> /root/.nuget/packages/postsharp/5.1.9-preview/build/PostSharp.targets(154,5): error MSB4062: The "PostSharp.MSBuild.PostSharp30ValidateLanguageVersion" task could not be loaded from the assembly /root/.nuget/packages/postsharp/5.1.9-preview/build/PostSharp.MSBuild.v5.1.9.Release.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: PostSharp does not support building on Linux yet.

Comment: Do you clear it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [Requirements on development workstations and build servers](http://doc.postsharp.net/requirements), linux is not supported.

> Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8.1, Windows 10, Windows Server 2008 SP2,
>   Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012
>   R2, Windows Server 2016